# Find files by size and copy them to other directory

Tags: unix, copy, find

I would like to find files with size less than 10Mb and copy them to a different folder. I have a unix command but it's not conserving folders, just copying files:

```
find . -size -10Mb -exec cp {} /Users/bernardo/Desktop/copia \;
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Also see [How can I find files that are bigger/smaller than x bytes?](http://superuser.com/q/204564/173513) on Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-exec cp -p --parents -t/Users/bernardo/Desktop/copia/ {} +
```

The key part is --parents, to mirror the directory structure. I used -p to preserve mode, timestamp, and ownership. I find `-exec {} +` more intuitive than `-exec {} ;`, but it doesn't matter here, beyond the need to reorder arguments to cp with the former.