# How to recursively copying only small files?

Tags: shell

Which linux shell command should I use to copy all the files that are less than 5M in a tree structure ?

(I would like to keep this structure in the copied output).

Comment: there are similar questions in the site. Did you check them?

Comment: I couldn't find any, sorry :(

Comment: With a second check I still don't find this kind of question, if you have a link, I would be happy to check.

Comment: Well, at least you should find the basic [How can I find files that are bigger/smaller than x bytes?](http://superuser.com/q/204564/204979). Then, for the same case as here: [Find files by size and copy them to other directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19820755/1983854)

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -size -5M -exec cp -r {} dest/ \;
```

Comment: are you sure? what you mean by subdirectory structure?

Comment: well, there are a whole hierarchy of directory on my filesystem, I need to fetch all the small files on it. This command just copied all the small files in one directory, without keeping the tree of directory (I am not usre I am clear). It seems that we miss the '--parents' option on the copy).

Comment: I did   $ find . -size -2M -exec cp -r --parents {] ./dest/ \;      <= this copied all the files on [dest] even the big one of 200 M :-s

Comment: Try this: `find . -size -2M -exec cp -a {} ./dest/ \;`

Comment: still don't keep the sub-dir structure